# How to update or use helpful flags in my profile? What is the meaning of helpful tag?

Tags: support, flags

Since I am in stackoverflow, every day I checked my profile and it update the my activity.

But I don't know about "0 helpful tags", at top users have some value here. So how I can use or useful for me this line.

What is meaning say this line?

Comment: Why do you think there's a bug? Assuming you mean *"helpful flags"*, it tells you how many flags you've raised that were considered helpful - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that a post or comment you have flagged (assuming you have flagged any) has been marked as helpful by whomever handled the flag.

If you don't flag anything, this will never go up.

Comment: no I never done this, how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts